# count the lines of a program in python

Tags: python, command

I found this question in a textbook to write code to count the number of lines of program by running it.

This is what I have:

```
import commands,os,sys

def count_lines(modul):
    cmd="wc -l " + modul +" | awk '{print $1}'"
    return commands.getoutput(cmd)


if __name__=='__main__':
    print count_lines(sys.modules[__name__].__file__)
```

It seems to work;but I am not sure if this the right way to do. I thought this is simpler.

Comment: You're not really writing Python there. You're writing a shell script in a Python wrapper.

Comment: `wc -l "file" | awk '{print $1}'` will work without python.

Comment: @user2357112: I agree; but most of the python functions are wrappers of `C`. correct me if I am wrong..?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: Whether that's true or false (I consider it false), it's not relevant. They're definitely not wrappers around shell scripting (which is entirely distinct from C), and whatever the implementation of Python, there's no reason to embed a second programming language and spawn several additional processes just to perform this simple task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print "I AM %d LINES LONG"%len(list(open(__file__)))` just put that in any file...

if you insist on closing your file (while a good habit , not necessary in cython especially when only reading)

```
with open(__file__) as f:
    print "I AM %d LINES LONG"%len(list(f))
```

Comment: you dont need that ... and it would be readlines I think ... but by default it will iterate into a list right?

Comment: it has to count the lines of the file that this line is present? will it work?

Comment: Ah yeah, he is asking for the lines. My bad.

Comment: `open` without a `close` or `with`? Don't teach bad habits; close your file.

Comment: it doesnt matter if hes just reading and hes in cython ... but edited all the same ...